# Microtype package with Libertine font

Tags: microtype, libertine

In the microtype documentation it advices one to use settings that complement one's choice of font. I use libertine font. Does anyone know of any options or settings that specifically suit this font?

Comment: What do you mean by `microtype` settings for Libertine font? I only used `\usepackage[letterspace=30]{microtype}` for headings font.

Comment: There aren't, AFAIK. You can try looking at `mt-ptm.cfg` and perhaps `mt-pmn.cfg` to draw inspiration.

Comment: I have preliminary `microtype` config files for Libertine and Biolinum [which can be downloaded here](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/microtype-config/src). I'm sure they can be improved, though...

Comment: @cgnieder: when you think it's ready, submit it to the package maintainer for inclusion in the libertine package.

Comment: @KOF What I meant was just that since fonts have different properties, there might be certain microtype options or settings that work will with those properties.

Comment: Also, [here](http://pastebin.com/bSHJ4zFT) are some basic settings (haven't tested them yet, though).

Comment: @user22108 I will but since I only have _very_ limited micro-typographic experience this may take a while. I'm not even sure how I will judge if the files are ready or not.

Comment: @cgnieder Any news about the package?

Comment: @egreg well, the config files are usable (I use them all the time)... but especially the protrusion lists can surely be improved... I could write an answer (with some caveats), though

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I created a few preliminary config files for `microtype` and `libertine` for usage with `pdflatex`. They're publicly available from my Bitbucket site.

- [bitbucket.org/cgnieder/microtype-config](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/microtype-config/src)

They're all named `mt-<fontname>.cfg` and if placed in a suitable place in the local TEXMF tree will be picked up automatically by `microtype`.  This files are *far* from being complete and surely need a lot of improvement as can be seen in the output of the following sample document. Especially the protrusion lists still are more or less simply those for Computer Modern:

```
% part of `mt-LinuxLibertineT-OsF.cfg':
\SetProtrusion[name=LLO,load=cmr-T1]{
  encoding = *,
  family   = LinuxLibertineT-OsF
}{
  {,} = { ,600},
   -  = {400,600},
   ?  = {200,300}
}
```

Unfortunately my typographic knowledge is one based on the reading of a few books and my untrained eyes. If someone more experienced likes to improve those files I'd be more than happy.

---

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{microtype}
% this is the contents of my `microtype.cfg':
% \DeclareMicrotypeSet{scshape}{
%   encoding = {*} ,
%   shape    = {sc,scit,si}
% }
% \DeclareMicrotypeSet{romansans}{
%   encoding = {*},
%   family   = {rm*,sf*}
% }
\microtypesetup{
  tracking   = scshape ,
  protrusion = romansans ,
  expansion  = romansans
}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]