# How well does microtype "font expansion" work with LuaLaTeX?

Tags: luatex, microtype

Using LuaLaTeX and a an OpenType font loaded with `fontspec` (like, say, Linux Libertine), can the "font expansion" feature of `microtype` be considered stable and fully functional? And can I feel safe by just loading `microtype` with the default settings, or is it necessary to make manual adjustments depending on the font in question?

Comment: As long as you're using version 2.5 or later of `microtype`, version 0.62 or later of LuaTeX, and create pdf files directly (i.e., without a detour via a dvi file), the user guide of the `microtype` package says that the expansion feature is fully functional. See section 5.7 (and Table 3) of the user guide for a discussion of font-specific configuration files. The package comes with various such files. If the font you use is sufficiently unique, you may find it necessary to create your own font-specific config file to obtain optimal results.

Comment: I have read the corresponding section but found it hard to translate into human language; namely, when using fonts that are not on the list (like exactly Linux Libertine), will it be necessary to make such files, or is Libertine so "standard" that I can use the default settings?

Comment: I'd give the Times and Palatino config files a try. I doubt you'll find much difference (at least as far as font expansion is concerned).

Comment: Or perhaps http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97193/microtype-package-with-libertine-font

Comment: BTW, where exactly should I put those files? I'm using TeX Live 2014 on Windows 8.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't "do" Windows. As a result, I can't provide advice on where the file(s) should be stored.